# XNA WP7 Mango: DrawableGameComponent can be dynamically added to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game?

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-7.1, drawablegamecomponent

It seems that the class inherited from DrawableGameComponent can be added to Xna.Framework.Game only at Initialize() phase in Game1. Later than that, the component's Draw won't be called. Is there any workaround? The components can be dynamically created at run-time. I need to add the component to be drawn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Components can be addded to the `Game.Components` collection whereever you want. If you add a component in the e.g. Update() method, even its `Initialize()` and `LoadContent()` methods are called. To draw all components, make sure that the `Game.Draw()` method contains a call to `base.Draw()`.

If you are experiencing problems only because components are added later, then the problem is probably in the component itself or somewhere else. Make sure that everything exists that the component relies on.